# Android Multi Language Keyboard Support for an application

Tags: android, keyboard, multilingual

Is there any way we can provide multi-language keyboard support for an application. I need to provide support for 8 international languages in an application.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own keyboards for different languages, no built in keyboards are provided for this.  You just have to add buttons with respective characters and with it you can easily make your own keyboard.